# Visual Studio Community 2019 recent update 16.7.0 issue with Word web addin

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, office-js, word-addins

I was working on MS Word Web Add-in project which was working completely fine then i chose to update my visual studio and since then i am getting this error.

"failed to launch debug adapter operation cancelled"

I have done every single solution provided over the internet even repaired my visual studio. All other projects are working completely fine. Please its an important project i need a solution to revert my update.

PS: My enable JS option in debugging is off.

I later installed vs 2019 professional which was working fine then suddenly it started giving the same exact error.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: [Office JS Addin Project will not start in VS 2019 but works fine in VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64228327/office-js-addin-project-will-not-start-in-vs-2019-but-works-fine-in-vs-2017)

Not sure why Microsoft haven't updated the VS template. Pretty poor change management IMO.